# Prove that $d(d(w)) = 0$ for a differential $n$-form $w$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I've managed to get that for the case of $w = a_Idx_I$, we have by the leibniz rule $d(d(w)) = d(d(a_I)) \wedge dx_I - da_I \wedge d(dx_I)$. The first term is $0$ because $a_I$ is a $0$-form. But why does the second term evaluate to $0$? How do I calculate $d(dx_I)$?

Comment: How is $d$ defined for you? Are you assuming that $d$ is an antiderivation?

Comment: $d$ is the exterior derivative, I've clarified in the title.

Comment: What is the definition of the exterior derivative of a 1-form that you are using here?

Comment: @noamchomsky There are many ways to define the exterior derivative $d$. One way is as as the unique antiderivation which agrees with the differential on $0$-forms. Are you using that definition?

Comment: My definition is from Bachman's "A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms": $dw(V^1,...,V^{n+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{i+1}\nabla_{V^i}w(V^1, ... ,V^{i-1}, V^{i+1}, ... ,v^{n+1})$

Comment: And what happens when you apply the definition to $d(dx_I)$?

Comment: @noamchomsky That definition is not accurate unless $[V^i, V^j] = 0$ for all $i,j$. If we use that definition, then $d(df)(V^1, V^2) = [V^1, V^2]f$ for any $0$-form $f$. Are you sure you have the right definition?

Comment: @noamchomsky To be more exact, since I'm not 100% certain what $\nabla_{V^i}$ means in your notation, we would have $d(df)(V^1, V^2) = (\nabla_{V^1} df(V^2) - \nabla_{V^2} df(V^1)$, which there is no reason to think should be equal to $0$ in general.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins sorry for the confusion, what $\nabla_{V^1}w(V^2)$ means is the gradient of $w(V^2)$ dotted with the vector $V^1$, or in other words the directional derivative in the direction of $V^1$.

Comment: Do you have a Riemmanian metric on your manifold?

Comment: @noamchomsky in that case my first comment stands. The definition you have does not define an exterior derivative. It would only work if $[V_i , V_j] = 0$ for all $i,j$, in which case you should just work in local coordinates.